# Cannot set badge number after a push notification arrival

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, badge

In an app that I'm working on (iOS 11), to update the badge number we use:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = number
```

The app updates the badge number with the value provided without problems.

And then...

A push notification arrives with the "badge" key, the app updates the badge number with the push notification value, BUT, from there all the updates using the **applicationIconBadgeNumber** wont work anymore. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement UserNotifications into `AppDelegate`.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Use the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Your Code 
        }
    }
    return true

}
```

For badge update, you need to use the following code

```
let alert = UNMutableNotificationContent() 
alert.badge = 10 //your badge count
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tested the UNMutableNotificationContent() code and now I cannot update the badge number at all, only thru the remove notification.